# How to change from oracle trigger to oracle compound trigger?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

I have to change from given Oracle trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MY_TRIGGER
    AFTER UPDATE OF STATUS ON T_TABLE_A
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE T_TABLE_B T
    SET T.STATUS = :NEW.STATUS
    WHERE T.REF_ID = :NEW.ID;
END;
/
```

to an Oracle compound trigger. Effect must be the same. My approach is now:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MY_NEW_TRIGGER
        for insert or update on T_TABLE_A
        compound trigger
        before statement -- STUB
        is
        begin
          null;
        end before statement;
            before each row
            is
     begin
            end before each row;

     after each row -- STUB
            is
     begin
         --IDEA: collect ids of changed records (T_TABLE_A) here >> in a global variable? array?
            end after each row;

    after statement -- STUB
     is
     begin
              --IDEA: Bulk Update of T_TABLE_B (goal is: update T_TABLE_B.STATUS column; must be the same as T_TABLE_A.STATUS)
            end after statement;
      end;
/
```

But as a Java Developer I am very slow to find out the correct syntax of variables, arrays and simple DB scriptings, so any approach is helpful.

Approach where to start is marked as "IDEA".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see you have almost done the half of the job , I amended the code to `IDEA` part.

I have not included the `before statement` part and also the triggering clause and all you can adjust according to your need. I just considered for updating the status column in my code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_trigger
   FOR UPDATE OF status ON t_table_a
   COMPOUND TRIGGER

   -- record type to hold each record updated in t_table_a 
   -- columns we are intersted in are id and status
   TYPE table_a_rec IS RECORD(
       id     t_table_a.id%TYPE
      ,status t_table_a.status%TYPE);

   --table type based on record to access each record using this
   TYPE table_a_row_data_t IS TABLE OF table_a_rec INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

   -- global variable for the compound trigger
   g_row_level_data table_a_row_data_t;

   AFTER EACH ROW IS
   BEGIN
      -- IDEA: collect ids of changed records (T_TABLE_A) here >> in a global variable? array?
      g_row_level_data(g_row_level_data.count + 1).id := :new.id;
      g_row_level_data(g_row_level_data.count).status := :new.status;
   END AFTER EACH ROW;

   AFTER STATEMENT IS
   BEGIN
      --IDEA: Bulk Update of T_TABLE_B (goal is: update T_TABLE_B.STATUS column; must be the same as T_TABLE_A.STATUS)
      FORALL i IN 1 .. g_row_level_data.count
         UPDATE t_table_b t
            SET t.status = g_row_level_data(i).status
          WHERE t.ref_id = g_row_level_data(i).id;
   END AFTER STATEMENT;
END my_trigger;
/
```